# Cannot divide a long string into pieces

Tags: java, android, arrays

There is a long string- "sourceMeaning" which consists of some sentences retrieved from a SQLiteDatabase. I used "&" to separate the sentences like below:

```
SentenceA&SentenceB&SentenceC .....
```

After the long string has been retrieved, the string will be divided to:

```
SentenceA 
SentenceB
SentenceC 
....
```

I used a String array (Meanings) to store the divided sentences and applied the following codes to finish the task, but it throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when executing...

```
String sourceMeaning=c.getString(1);
Log.w("SourceMeaning",sourceMeaning);
String[] Meanings=new String[]{};
int j=0;
for (int i=0;i<=sourceMeaning.length();i++){
    if (sourceMeaning.charAt(i)!='&'){
        Meanings[j]=Meanings[j]+sourceMeaning.charAt(i);
        Log.w("Translated",Meanings[j]);
    } else {
        j+=1;
    }
}
```

How to divide the sentences without error?

Comment: i think you `Meanings` is empty, where you are populating it

Comment: So if i need to declare a int array/ string array in order to put something into it, how to initialize the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should split the initial string in this way

```
String sourceMeaning=c.getString(1);
Log.w("SourceMeaning",sourceMeaning);
String[] meanings = sourceMeaning.split("&");
```

you will have everything in that array

Comment: @LuftSchlafer, you're welcome :) if you liked my answer, please accept it or at least upvote it :) thanks

Comment: There's another question: If i need to build an integer array/ String array to store something, but the actual length is unknown; so how to declare and initialize the array to prevent array out of bound error?

Comment: @LuftSchlafer, make another question and link it here :)

Comment: @LuftSchlafer, you should study a little bit Java language :) you can use an ArrayList

Comment: ArrayList<String> or ArrayList<int> ?

Comment: ArrayList<String> for String and ArrayList<Integer> for int. Or do you want an object that will contain both kind of objects? please, add some upvote

Comment: Good, it seems the problem has been solved. Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the split() and then iterate through the generated array:

```
String[] sentences = sourceMeaning.split("&");
for (String sentence: sentences) {           
     //iterate through each one of the sentences, i.e:
     //SentenceA, SentenceB, ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure to totally get what you are trying to do, so i'm gonna answer this question:

> How to divide the sentences without error?

Using the split method of the String Class in Java

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split()` method to get your string to array like :

```
String[] Meanings = sourceMeaning.split("&");
```